# sbt not taking the correct the global plugin version

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

While building a sbt project using sbt assembly I am getting this error :

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.geirsson#sbt-scalafmt;1.5.1: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        ...
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.geirsson#sbt-scalafmt;1.5.1: not found
```

upon comparing the it with others I saw the difference was that my sbt was taking in wrong global plugin here :

```
❯ sbt assembly
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/<username>/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/<username>/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
```

it should have taken `.sbt/1.0/plugins` instead.

The `build.properties` is also has `sbt.version=1.1.4`

Doing `sbt --version` gives this result :

```
❯ sbt --version
[info] 1.1.4
sbt script version: 1.5.4
```

Things I tried :

- removing `.sbt/0.13/plugins`
- removing `~/.ivy2/cache`
- deleting and re cloning the project

Comment: What does `project/build.properties` say?

Comment: I don't have any clue but SBT 1.1.x is quite old, any chance you could use a more recent version in your project?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez : `❯ cat project/build.properties
sbt.version=1.1.4
`

Comment: Uhm, that is weird, I would also suggest upgrading to `1.7.2` both in the project and the launcher script.

Comment: If you try to reduce this to an MCVE that other people could reproduce on their own computers, you will almost certainly discover the cause yourself in the process.

Comment: I cannot upgrade the project version as it's an old project being used by various other people.